# Integer array where merge sort is faster than quicksort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm comparing merge sort and quick sort with integer arrays to see which one is faster in sorting the array and I already have one array set up where quick sort sorts it faster than merge sort but I can't figure out how to have one where merge sort is faster than quick sort. Can someone give me an example of one that does?
The array doesn't have to be huge it can have a small size like 20.

Comment: What is the pathological worst case input for quicksort?

Comment: I think its O(n^2)

Comment: But what kind of input causes that?

Comment: Where the worst possible pivot is chosen

Comment: You claim you are able to measure the difference for int arrays of a size of 20?

Comment: Ok, so how do you force that to happen?

Comment: Yes I have a time function which I use to determine which sort is faster.

Comment: Enable the optimizer.

Comment: By setting up its partitions to choose such cases

Comment: I guess the answer I was looking for was if there is any specific sequence of integers in an array where a merge sort would sort it faster than a quicksort could

Comment: No matter how you time things, all timing of sorting of a 20 element array is going to be in the statistical noise and won't actually show you anything (even bubble sort might win that). Try timing the sort of a 20.000 element array and do it 2.000 times or more. Then you *might* have some reasonable numbers you can draw conclusions from.

Comment: For your question; Try already sorted input...

Comment: That's several orders of magnitude too small for a timing function. I would count comparisons, instead. Of course, it is meaningless for small samples, as the whole point of complexity is predicting how it does with very large data sets (without having to actually do them). But if you figure out what Oliver Charlesworth is trying to tell you, that will also apply to large data sets (without having to actually do them).

Comment: Is there a restriction on the type of merge sort? On a processor with 16 registers, such as a PC in 64 bit mode, a 4-way merge sort may be faster than quicksort (depending on processor, cache, ... ).

Answer (score 2):

These two sorts have been analyzed mathematically and the results show that a [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis) is likely going to be faster in most cases.

```
O(n lg n)
```

The [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Formal_analysis) analysis shows a range and the best case scenario is equal to the Merge Sort timing:

```
O(n lg n) (best)
O(n²) (worst)
```

I think that the Wikipedia analysis explains pretty well why one is eventually faster than the other. As Kenny Ostrom commented on your question, what you should do is count the number of comparisons, which is not easy to do if you're implementation uses algorithms and with optimizations you never really know how many compares and branches are going to happen once you run the code (i.e. newer processors have conditional MOV instructions meaning that you can avoid branches altogether!)

However, if you are looking for a pure analysis, then speed in itself is not an issue (i.e. you don't need to time the function), but instead just count the number of times you do a compare and the number of times you swap two entries. This gives you the timing for a particular array of objects, whatever the objects (although the compare function could be really expensive: imagine comparing two images that require some OCR work before they can be sorted...)

**Why is speed not an issue when doing analysis?**

If you read the Merge Sort algorithm on Wikipedia, you will notice that they mention the fact that to reach  the best case scenario you need to properly implement the algorithm. So if you wrote it yourself or use a version that's not well implemented, then you could find that the Merge Sort is slower than the Quicksort.